# Splunk query using append

Tags: append, splunk, splunk-query

I have a query that calculates Batch logs from different time slots and shows the output using append command.But in the first time slot i'm getting a batch log which is not there in 2nd timeslot of the same query. In the output of the query after appending i'm not getting the logs that are appearing in only timeslot.

Query using

`index=main sourcetype=xml "MSR*" earliest=-30d latest=-15d`
in the above query i'm getting MSR1451 batch in the output.

`index=main sourcetype=xml "MSR*" earliest=-14d latest=now()`
in the above query, we are not getting that MSR1451 batch.

```
index=main sourcetype=xml "MSR*" earliest=-30d latest=-15d 
| fields jobName 
| eval marker="Before 15 days" 
| append 
    [search index=main sourcetype=xml "MSR*" earliest=-30d latest=-15d 
    |fields jobName 
    | eval marker="After 15 days"] 
| stats count (eval(marker="Before 15 days")) AS Before 15 days, count (eval(marker="After 15 days")) AS After 15 days by JobName
```

In the above query I'm getting only the common jobs that are appearing in both time slots. I need the jobs that appear in only one time slot also should be listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you meaning to use earliest=-30d and latest=-15d in your main search and sub search?

In the query you posted, you are using the same values for earliest and latest in both searches. You need to do:

`index=main sourcetype=xml "MSR*" earliest=-30d latest=-15d |fields jobName | eval marker="Before 15 days" | append [search index=main sourcetype=xml "MSR*" earliest=-15d latest=now() |fields jobName | eval marker="After 15 days"] | stats count (eval(marker="Before 15 days")) AS Before 15 days, count (eval(marker="After 15 days")) AS After 15 days by JobName`

Comment: In main search i want to use one time range and in subsearch another time range. Gave you the complete query above.Hope you got it

Comment: Thank you! I worked on top of the query and got the expected result. Sorry for the late response. Now I have another requirement. Need to search for the logs for the same day in last week. Can you help me with that.